# How to parse a JSON response in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, get

I'm creating a small web-app for my girlfriend and I that will allow us to keep track of the movies we want to watch together. To simplify the process of adding a movie to the list, I'm trying to use TheMovieDatabase.org's API (supports JSON only) to allow us to search for a movie by title, let the database load a few results, and then we can choose to just add a movie from the database or create our own entry if no results were found.

I'm using jQuery to handle everything and, having never used JSON before, am stuck. I wrote a short bit of code to get the JSON based on my search query, and am now trying to populate a `<ul>` with the results. Here's what I have.

```
var TMDbAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie";
var moviequery = $("#search").val();
var api_key = "baab01130a70a05989eff64f0e684599";

$ul = $('ul');
$.getJSON( TMDbAPI,
{
    query: moviequery,
    api_key: api_key
},
function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k,v) {
            $ul.append("<li>" + k + ": " + v + "</li>");
        }
    );
});
```

The JSON file is structured as

```
{
"page":1,
"results":[
    {
    "adult":false,
    "backdrop_path":"/hNFMawyNDWZKKHU4GYCBz1krsRM.jpg",
    "id":550,
    "original_title":"Fight Club",
    "release_date":"1999-10-14",
    "poster_path":"/2lECpi35Hnbpa4y46JX0aY3AWTy.jpg",
    "popularity":13.3095569670529,
    "title":"Fight Club",
    "vote_average":7.7,
    "vote_count":2927
    }, ...
"total_pages":1,
"total_results":10
}
```

but all I'm getting is

```
page: 1
results: [object Object], ...
total_pages: 1
total_results: 10
```

I've searched quite extensively on the Internet for a solution, but with the little knowledge I have of JSON I wasn't able to learn much from the various examples and answers I found scattered about. What do?

Comment: The api in sending what it supose to send.  If you want the movies you need to traverse data.results object

Comment: @Cheluis I know that the API is sending it correctly, I need to how to do whatever you said, because that is where my knowledge ends.

Comment: In the $.each function change data for data.results

Comment: @Cheluis: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Cheluis: I made the suggested edit, now I am given `0: [object Object],...` (0-9, the ten fields in Results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you'd like to do is write out some properties of each movie in the list. This means you want to loop over the list in `data.results`, like this:

```
// Visit each result from the "results" array
$.each(
    data.results,
    function (i, movie) {
        var $li = $('<li></li>');
        $li.text(movie.title);
        $ul.append($li);
    }
);
```

This will make a list of movie titles. You can access other properties of `movie` inside the `each` function if you want to show more elaborate information.

I added the title to the `li` using `$li.text` rather than simply doing `$('<li>' + movie.title + '</li>')` since this will avoid problems if any of the movie titles happen to contain `<` symbols, which could then get understood as HTML tags and create some funny rendering. Although it's unlikely that a movie title would contain that symbol, this simple extra step makes your code more robust and so it's a good habit to keep.

Comment: This gives me ten empty results :/

Comment: Yes Martin is right. I think you are parsing json but not defining the key value pair correctly.  Data.result[index]. title will give you the result you needed and set it as your requirements.

Comment: I have just corrected a bug in my example where I missed the first parameter `i` on the callback function. It should work now.

Comment: @martin I just figured that out at the same time you did apparently :) That did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the results object.  In the $.each function change data for data.results

Comment: I made the suggested edit, now I am given `0: [object Object],...` (0-9, the ten fields in Results)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the list/array. in the example below i am appending a list item containing the value of the key `results[i].title`. you can append the values of as many valid keys as you would like to the div.

```
var TMDbAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie";
var moviequery = $("#search").val();
var api_key = "baab01130a70a05989eff64f0e684599";

$ul = $('ul');
$.getJSON( TMDbAPI,
{query: moviequery,api_key: api_key},function(data){
    var results = data.results;//cast the data.results object to a variable
    //iterate over results printing the title and any other values you would like.
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        $ul.append("<li>"+ results[i].title +"</li>");
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I only wish I could say that worked haha. I'll keep on chuggin' along.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="query" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="search" />
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
        var TMDbAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie";
        var moviequery = $("#search").val();
        var api_key = "baab01130a70a05989eff64f0e684599";

        $.getJSON(TMDbAPI, {
            query: moviequery,
            api_key: api_key
        },

        function (data) {
            $("ul").remove();
            var ul = $("<ul>");
            $(ul).append("<li><i>total pages: <i>" 
                        + data.total_pages + "\n" 
                        + "<i>current page: </i>" 
                        + data.page 
                        + "</li>");
            $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
                $(ul).append("<li><i>title: </i>" 
                            + v.original_title + "\n" 
                            + "<i>release date: </i>" + v.release_date + "\n" 
                            + "<i>id: </i>" + v.id + "\n" 
                            + "<i>poster: </i>" 
                            + v.poster_path 
                            + "</li>");
            });
            $("body").append($(ul))
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/sLSHP/